# How to setup FastCGI setting of IIS with GDAL libs

Tags: python, django, iis, fastcgi, gdal

I set up a django website via IIS manager, which is working fine, then I add a function by using GDAL libs and the function is working fine.
And also it is fine if I run this website by using CMD with this command

`python path\manage.py runserver 8000`

But it cannot run via IIS

I got error is `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`, which from `from osgeo import gdal, osr`

My guess is I need to set environment variables to FastCGI Settings of IIS

I set these to  environment variables collections but does not work.

`GDAL_DATA     C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data`

`GDAL_DRIVER_PATH   C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by restart the machine

Comment: If they were done via FastCGI settings, you probably didn't need to reboot the whole thing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050119/5937168