# how i cant configure a domain by ejabberd, replace localhost:5280/admin?

Tags: iis, web-config, localhost, ejabberd, strophe

how i can replace to the domian http://localhost:5280/admin by http://server.com:5280/admin. And in my configurations start by get in login with localhost:5280/admin

I cant on my file ejabberd.yml

//SERVED HOSTNAMES

```
hosts:
  - "server.com"
```

On in file hosts.conf

// localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
0.0.0.0 localhost
1.1.1.1 localhost
'##192.168.0.1  server.com (it is my ip local)
```

On IIS urlrewrite file web.conf

`<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="xmpp-httpbind" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5280/bosh/{R:1}" />
</rule>`

Strophe client

```
var connection = null;
var server_dominio = 'server.com';
var BOSH_SERVICE  = '/xmpp-httpbind';
```

i can serach possible solution in this link https://github.com/jsxc/jsxc/issues/353 @skyfox675 but 
HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE/aplications"
The server variable "ORIGINAL_HOST21" is not allowed to be set. Add the server variable name to the allowed server variable list.

i have edit only file web.config

Comment: Solved whit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102024/how-to-add-a-server-variable-in-iis Put variable server on iis

Answer (score 0):

configure the server variable in this link step: [How to add a server variable in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102024/how-to-add-a-server-variable-in-iis)

configure file host

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
0.0.0.0 localhost
1.1.1.1 localhost
192.168.0.1  server.com
```

On IIS urlrewrite file web.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="86400" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^http-bind/" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server.com:5280/http-bind" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" /> 
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="/server.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Strophe client

```
var connection = null;
var server_dominio = 'server.com';
var BOSH_SERVICE  = 'http://192.168.0.1:5280/http-bind';
```